# Binary search tree effectively acts as linked list when items are added in an ordered way

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a huge number of items to be stored  in a collection. I need to locate an item by comparing it to a certain key and then tell if such an item exists. I use a binary search tree to do so.

```
class node
{
    public:
    node(const char *p_name) :
        greater(NULL),
        smaller(NULL),
        name(p_name)
    {}
    node *find(const char *p_name)
    {
        node *l_retval = this;

        for(; l_retval != NULL;)
        {
            int l = strcmp(p_name, l_retval->name.c_str());
            if (l == 0) break; // found it
            else
            if (l > 0) l_retval = greater; // the node searched for is in the 'greater' branch
            else l_retval = smaller; // or in the 'smaller' branch
        }
        return l_retval;
    }
    node *greater, *smaller;
    std::string name; // or any other type of data you would like to store
};
```

If the items are added in a random way, all is fine. If, on occasion, items are added in an ordered way, my BST acts as a linked list (slow).

The question is: Given a BST (balanced or linked list style), how can I 'balance' the BST, so it is rearranged and not effectively acting as a linked list?

The example is in C++, but the problem applies to more languages than C++ allone.

If you provide me with links that could help me, thanks!

Comment: If you have some spare time at the beginning, you can sort the input and insert each item into the tree in such a way that you insert them in an optimal way into the tree and it's perfect when you start off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use a self-balancing tree (red-black, AVL, etc.), then the "easy" solution is to just shuffle the collection before inserting it into the tree.

If you want a perfectly balanced tree, you could start with a sorted collection, then insert the middle element of that list into the tree and recursively do the same with the two remaining sorted subcollections.

I understand that you are investigating algorithms, but in real-life you'd probably just want to use a `std::map` and not worry about the details of how it works.

Answer (score 3):

It is the the concept of a BST.

Now what you are looking for are derivates, not pure:

#### [Self-balancing binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)

> Self-balancing binary trees solve this problem by performing transformations on the tree (such as tree rotations) at key times, in order to keep the height proportional to log2(n). Although a certain overhead is involved, it may be justified in the long run by ensuring fast execution of later operations.
>
> Maintaining the height always at its minimum value  is not always viable; it can be proven that any insertion algorithm which did so would have an excessive overhead.[citation needed] Therefore, most self-balanced BST algorithms keep the height within a constant factor of this lower bound

The most popular variant of the self-balancing trees is without much doubt the Red-Black Tree

#### Links

Wikipedia is quite authoritative on trees an tree algorithms:

- [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)

  > **Note** *"In either version, this operation requires time proportional to the height of the tree in the worst case, which is O(log n) time in the average case over all trees, but O(n) time in the worst case."* <-- this is your point

  and under **Sort** :

  > *"The worst-case time of `build_binary_tree` is O(n2)—if you feed it a sorted list of values, it chains them into a linked list with no left subtrees. For example, `build_binary_tree`([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) yields the tree (1 (2 (3 (4 (5)))))"*
- [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree)

Comment: I could rearrange the nodes so that al items are preserved and most nodes do have both a 'greater' and a 'smaller' node. I can't believe it's impossible!

Comment: AFAICT avl trees are most often taught but not implemented as often in the wild. (AVL trees share the same features and performance characteristics with red-black trees; IIRC red-black trees are considerably simpler to implement (_correctly_))

Answer (score 1):

The first question that comes to mind is why do you want to implement this? Use an `std::set` or `std::map`. Both implement balanced trees. You will need to provide an ordering function, but besides that (and the obvious limitation that you cannot modify the field that sets the order) it should be fine.

If you already have the elements stored in another container, you can use a map from the key that controls the order to a pointer/iterator into the original container (beware of any operations in the container that might invalidate pointers/iterators)

Answer (score 1):

YOu have [AVL trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

A trick is to use an alternative compare function (eg some kind of hash, or just random) to move the linked list to a new linked list, and than consume the temporary list and re-insert into the original tree.

```
int node_cmp_random(struct node *one, struct node *two)
{       
return (rand() %2) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

UPDATE: randomising in place (C code)

```
void node_randomise(struct node **tpp)
{
struct node *new, *this, **hnd;

for (new=NULL; this = node_consume( tpp); ) {
    for (hnd= &new; *hnd; hnd = (rand()&1) ? &(*hnd)->prev : &(*hnd)->next) {;}
    *hnd = this;
    }
*tpp = new ;
}

struct node * node_consume(struct node **tpp)
{
struct node * ret;
if (!*tpp) return NULL;

while ((*tpp)->prev) tpp = &(*tpp)->prev;
ret = *tpp;
*tpp = ret->next;
ret->next = NULL;
return ret;
}
```

Changing this code to use a function argument is obvious, and left as an exercise to the reader.